# What is the best way to get information from this website's table where html elements are hidden?

Tags: java, html, database, web-scraping

There is a website that holds information on all courses in a university. I would like to retrieve this information from this site if possible.

```
http://coursefinder.utoronto.ca/course-search/search/courseSearch?viewId=CourseSearch-FormView&methodToCall=start
```

The website contains links for each department below the search bar. If you click a link, a table appears with all the courses that belong to the respective department. I checked the page source code, and the elements for each course are of the hidden type. If you click on one of the courses, a new tab opens where all the information belonging to that course is displayed.

An example of a course link looks like:

```
http://coursefinder.utoronto.ca/course-search/search/courseInquiry?methodToCall=start&viewId=CourseDetails-InquiryView&courseId=LTE299Y1Y20199#.XgF_dUdKhPY
```

I noticed that by changing the courseId attribute, we can get information on any course and easily scrape the data as the html is not hidden.

My initial thought process was that I could scrape each department link, then for each department I would get all course IDs, navigate to each courses' display page and grab the information.

The main problem is that navigating to the link for every course is slow, as we're loading a new page for each course. Since there are thousands of courses, this will take a lot of time in total.

I know that what I'm asking for may be out of the question, but is there any faster way I could get information for all courses? Is it possible to access the database (without credentials), or maybe the javascript that gets the info, or anything of the sort?

Comment: IMO the most you can use is create multiple thread to process different courses.

Comment: can you give an example for just the first output how it's will looks like?

Comment: @Plochie I'm thinking the same honestly

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη if you look at the example course link, the page source code contains information of the course id, division, course description, department, course level, campus, term, and all lectures/practicals/tutorials. An example output would be a HashMap or dictionary representing the course where each key and value represents the information given from the course link

Comment: check that, and i think that you know from where to start now http://coursefinder.utoronto.ca/course-search/search/courseSearch/course/search?queryText=&requirements=&campusParam=St.%20George,Scarborough,Mississauga

Comment: I'm Python dev, and your case can be done easily via Python, so it's can be done with Java also, you can call the link and fetch all in one for all. or by your method with multithreading

Comment: I tried using that link already but the get request to that url in code doesn't return the courses, it returns the departments

Answer (score 0):

Further to your original idea:

Searching *** will return all of the available course. The results are paginated but if you look at your Developer Tool> Network tab you can see the json directly which loads the full results in 1 request (link earlier given by @αԋɱҽԃ-αмєяιcαη ).

> http://coursefinder.utoronto.ca/course-search/search/courseSearch?viewId=CourseSearch-FormView&methodToCall=start#search

You would need a scraper of some kind (BeautifulSoup?) from there to just **loop through** the courseID pages and extract the fields that you want and append it to a file.

> http://coursefinder.utoronto.ca/course-search/search/courseInquiry?methodToCall=start&viewId=CourseDetails-InquiryView&courseId=**ACMB01H3F20199**

Comment: When I click on that first link, I get a list of all the courses. However, when I send a get request from my code to the same URL, I am not getting all the courses. Instead, I am getting the departments

Comment: @Bbolt Yup, sorry. The first link will just load the search page. Entering a search query will result in a GET request being sent (link below) which will return a json file. The search page will load the json into the table.

You can just scrape the json response to get the courseID

http://coursefinder.utoronto.ca/course-search/search/courseSearch/course/search?queryText=***&requirements=&campusParam=St.%20George,Scarborough,Mississauga

Comment: this helps, but I'm getting a 403 status error when trying to fetch that URL. I set the user-agent, but I'm still being blocked. any suggestions?

Comment: @Bbolt You may also have to include other items in the request (Referrer url, cookie?).

In any case, this looks like a one time off task, so why not just browse the search page manually to reach to the json file. Download it normally and then parse the json locally to get the courseID urls and go from there.

Comment: i can't do that because the courses may change at random times, i need to get my program to do that update on it's own